# saving the state of a SeekBar

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to find the best way to implement my update to the database

The code below is in the adapter for a list view, so each list item has its own seekbar.

The list is of homework assignments so each item has its own degree of completion which I need to persist to a database.

I have a *business method* which can do the database write, it just needs the id of the assignment and the new progress value.

```
private void attachProgressUpdatedListener(SeekBar seekBar) {
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // need to update database with new progress here!

    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // empty as onStartTrackingTouch listener not being used in
    // current implementation

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // empty as onProgressChanged listener not being used in current
    // implementation

    }
});

}
```

the problem I'm having is getting a handle to my AssignmentHandler which deals with the database reads / writes. I can pass the assignment_id to my attachProgressUpdatedListener without any issues but I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it as I haven't got / not sure I want an instance of AssignmentHandler instantiated inside the ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the element's database ID in each SeekBar's "tag" (setTag() and getTag() methods), and use that to update the database from the onStopTracking method.